# Upon selecting a radio button, how do I use its value to dynamically update another PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Im currently building an online store and im in the process of integrating delivery costs onto the checkout page so that when a user selects one of the two radio buttons the TOTAL PRICE updates to reflect the postage costs selection.

HTML Code:

```html
<h1 id='h1_centre'> Your Cart </h1>
 
<div id="shopping-cart">

<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <th style='text-align:left; font-size: 1.5em;'><strong>Product</strong></th>     
 <th style='text-align:left; font-size: 1.5em;'><strong></strong></th>
 <th style='text-align:left; font-size: 1.5em;'> <strong>Description</strong></th>    
 <th style='text-align:left; font-size: 1.5em;'><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
 <th style='text-align:left; font-size: 1.5em;'><strong>Price</strong></th>             
 <th style='text-align:left; font-size: 1.5em;'><strong>VAT</strong></th>
 <th style='text-align:right; font-size: 1.5em;'><strong>Total</strong></th>
 <th style='text-align:right; font-size: 1.5em;'></th>              
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
 <div id="product_image_checkout_large">
 <img src="../images/pillows.png"
 </div>
</td>
<td>Pillows</td><td>Enter Text Here - Extra Information</td><td>1</td> 
<td>£20.00</td><td>£4.00</td><td style='text-align: right;'>£24.00</td> 
<td style='text-align:right;'>
  
<form action='remove_cart_item.php' method='post'>
   <input type='text' name='cart_item' value='10' style='display: none;'>
  <button type='submit' value='Remove' style='background: none; border: none;'>
   <img src='../images/removal_cross.png' style='width: 25px; height: 25px'> 
 </button>
 </form>
 </td> 
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='8' align=right style='font-size: 1.2em;'> Total: £24.00
    </td>
 </tr> 
  
  <tr>
  <td colspan='7' align=right style='font-size: 1em;'>
   <input type='radio' name='delivery' value='9.99' checked>1st Class - £9.99
  </td>
  <td colspan='7' align=right style='font-size: 1em;'>
    <input type='radio' name='delivery' value='2.99' checked>2nd Class - £2.99
  </td>
 </tr>    
 <tr>
  <td colspan="8" align=right style="font-size: 1.5em;" > 
                        £26.99                    
  </td>
</tr>    
<tr>
 <td colspan="8" align=left >      
  <!-- Button -->

      
  </td>
</tr>    
</tbody>
</table>   

</div>
```

PHP Code that generates the **total cost** based on shopping cart entries data from SQL:

```
$sql3="SELECT SUM(total_with_vat) FROM shopping_cart WHERE username='$myusername'";

// Posting Result
$result3 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql3);

// Counting Results 
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result3);

if($count==0) {

} else {
if ($result3 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql3)){
       while($row = $result3->fetch_array()) {
           $total_new_vat = $row['0'];
         echo "<tr ><td colspan='8' align=right style='font-size: 1.2em;'> Total: "."£".$total_new_vat."</td></tr>";

   }

}
```

PHP Code to generate radio buttons for 2 **postage options**:

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include "$root/ecommerce/connection.php";

echo "<tr >";
$sql4="SELECT * FROM delivery_charges where active= 'yes'";
      // Posting Result
      $result4 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql4);

      // Counting Results   
      $count=mysqli_num_rows($result4);

      if($count==0) {

       } else {

       if ($result4 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql4)){
            while($row = $result4->fetch_array()) {
                    $class = $row['type'];
                    $delivery_amount = $row['amount'];
                    echo "<td colspan='7' align=right style='font-size: 1em;'><input type='radio' name='delivery' value='$delivery_amount' checked>$class - "."£".$delivery_amount."</td>";
          }

  }
```

When a user selects a radio button I want the TOTAL PRICE to update to include this, without the page reloading.

I understand that I need some JS code to manipulate the on page code, but id love some help on how to do this.

Thanks.
Stan.

Comment: Can you include a sample of your HTML code?

Comment: Hey, ive now added my HTML code for you :)

Comment: Please don't `$result3 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql3)` twice.  ...nor `$result4 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql4)` twice.  Variables are defined so that you can use the same value multiple times.  If you are only going to use a value once, don't declare it as a variable (`$root` is pointless to define).  Please don't mix object-oriented with procedure mysqli syntax.

Comment: Thanks for that, although analysis of my php code wasnt really the question ....

Comment: It all depends on your strategy for computing and tracking values in the cart. You can do it all inside the browser, or you can ask the server via ajax.  Either way, you’ll need to have a solid understanding of JavaScript, and preferably a library such as jquery to easily interact with the dom. Right now, it would be difficult to implement the js because you don’t have the presentation (html) separated from the logic. When you’re working with much JavaScript, you don’t want to have to go in and out of php. If you can do the html without a single echo or print, the JavaScript is much easier.

Comment: Once you have the code refactored, you can decide how you want to track the cart values. You can store everything in a JavaScript object and have JavaScript fill in the input values, or you can submit the form using ajax and receive the values back as a Json object, which would then be used by JavaScript to fill in the input values. The latter is probably the approach I would take.  But your question is too broad for me to go much further with it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `Jquery`, a `Javascript` framework. For that you have to include the `Jquery` framework file in your view page which is written in `Javascript`. Add below code at the bottom section of your view page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Now, you have to create a click event function when any of the radio button is clicked. for that, add the below code in both radio input tags.

```
onclick="add_delivery_cost(this.value)"
```

This will call the `add_delivery_cost()` by passing the value of radio input on clicking radio buttons.

Before defining `add_delivery_cost()`, add an `id` attribute to the `<td>` in which total price is displayed as given below. Using this id selector we will be changing the price data.

```
<td colspan='8' align=right style='font-size: 1.2em;' id="total-price-td"> Total: £24.00</td>
```

Just below the above code add an hidden input like below,

```
<input type="hidden" id="total-price" value="24.00">
```

By this we will get the current total price in `add_delivery_cost()` and can do further processing.

Now its time to define the `add_delivery_cost()`. For that add below script just below the `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>` that we have added above.

```
    <script>
      var price_string=$('#total-price').val();
      function add_delivery_cost(val){
          var delivery_cost=parseFloat(val);//Converting to float value//Returns  24.00
          var price=parseFloat(price_string);//Converting to float value
          var total_price=(price+delivery_cost).toFixed(2);//Adding delivery cost to price and rounding to 2 decimal points
          var price_html=' Total: £'+total_price;
          $('#total-price-td').html(price_html);//Updating the `html` content of total-price with a new value after adding delivery cost to the price.
      }
  </script>
```

Now price will be changing regarding the radio buttons when its clicked.

**Full reverted HTML code is given below.**

```html
<h1 id='h1_centre'> Your Cart </h1>
 
<div id="shopping-cart">

<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <th style='text-align:left; font-size: 1.5em;'><strong>Product</strong></th>     
 <th style='text-align:left; font-size: 1.5em;'><strong></strong></th>
 <th style='text-align:left; font-size: 1.5em;'> <strong>Description</strong></th>    
 <th style='text-align:left; font-size: 1.5em;'><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
 <th style='text-align:left; font-size: 1.5em;'><strong>Price</strong></th>             
 <th style='text-align:left; font-size: 1.5em;'><strong>VAT</strong></th>
 <th style='text-align:right; font-size: 1.5em;'><strong>Total</strong></th>
 <th style='text-align:right; font-size: 1.5em;'></th>              
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
 <div id="product_image_checkout_large">
 <img src="../images/pillows.png"
 </div>
</td>
<td>Pillows</td><td>Enter Text Here - Extra Information</td><td>1</td> 
<td>£20.00</td><td>£4.00</td><td style='text-align: right;'>£24.00</td> 
<td style='text-align:right;'>
  
<form action='remove_cart_item.php' method='post'>
   <input type='text' name='cart_item' value='10' style='display: none;'>
  <button type='submit' value='Remove' style='background: none; border: none;'>
   <img src='../images/removal_cross.png' style='width: 25px; height: 25px'> 
 </button>
 </form>
 </td> 
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='8' align=right style='font-size: 1.2em;' id="total-price-td"> Total: £24.00
    <input type="hidden" id="total-price" value="24.00">
    </td>
 </tr> 
  
  <tr>
  <td colspan='7' align=right style='font-size: 1em;'>
   <input type='radio' name='delivery' value='9.99' onclick="add_delivery_cost(this.value)" checked>1st Class - £9.99
  </td>
  <td colspan='7' align=right style='font-size: 1em;'>
    <input type='radio' name='delivery' value='2.99' onclick="add_delivery_cost(this.value)" checked>2nd Class - £2.99
  </td>
 </tr>    
 <tr>
  <td colspan="8" align=right style="font-size: 1.5em;" > 
                        £26.99                    
  </td>
</tr>    
<tr>
 <td colspan="8" align=left >      
  <!-- Button -->

      
  </td>
</tr>    
</tbody>
</table>   

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script>
      var price_string=$('#total-price').val();
      function add_delivery_cost(val){
          var delivery_cost=parseFloat(val);//Converting to float value//Returns  24.00
          var price=parseFloat(price_string);//Converting to float value
          var total_price=(price+delivery_cost).toFixed(2);//Adding delivery cost to price and rounding to 2 decimal points
          var price_html=' Total: £'+total_price;
          $('#total-price-td').html(price_html);//Updating the `html` content of total-price with a new value after adding delivery cost to the price.
      }
  </script>
```